# SimpleTest: assertEquals and PHP types

Tags: php, string, types, integer, simpletest

Considering the following code:

```
<?php
class Foo extends UnitTestCase {
    public function testFoo() {
        $foo = new Foo();
        $this->assertEqual('2, 3', $foo->bar(3));
    }
}
?>

<?php
class Foo {
    public function bar() {
        return 2;
    }
}
?>
```

'2, 3' == $foo->bar (2) because PHP allow that. This test pass! But it is wrong in some cases ('2, 3' string is different from 2 integer.

SimpleTest test method from EqualExpectation class:

```
function test($compare) {
    return (($this->value == $compare) && ($compare == $this->value));
}
```

Is there a method to test that in SimpleTest? Instead of ==, a method that uses === ...
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From the [SimpleTest documents](http://www.simpletest.org/en/unit_test_documentation.html):

```
assertIdentical($x, $y) Fail if $x == $y is false or a type mismatch
```